# Convert values of a list in dictionary to upper/lower case

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary in `python` like below

```
my_dict = {u'customer': [u'GS808E', u'GS810EMX'], u'tablets': [u'Apple IPAD PRO', u'Apple IPAD MINI', u'IPAD'], u'gaming_consoles': [u'SONY PLAYSTATION 4', u'XBOX ONE S', u'PLAYSTATION'], u'range_of_days': 14 }
```

I want to convert all the `values` in this `dictionary` to `lowercase` or `uppercase`

I have done like below.

```
new_dict = {k:[i.lower() for i in v] for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

I am getting the below error in `Python 2.7`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Is it lowercase or uppercase?

Comment: By the way, your code works for this data, so I think the problem is with your actual data.

Comment: There must be an integer in one of your values i.e `[u'Apple IPAD PRO', 43]` later on in your dataset.

Comment: Your code still works.

Comment: I concur, Code works. Have some water, take a deep breath and look at your original code again.

Comment: @coldspeed Now it doesn't works with updated dict

Comment: `[[i.lower() for i in v] if isinstance(v, list) else v for k,v in my_dict.items()]`

Comment: Perhaps `{k : list(map(str.lower, v)) if isinstance(v, list) else v for k, v in my_dict.iteritems()}`

Comment: great! good luck debugging.

Comment: @user9367133 No its giving it right `{u'customer': [u'gs808e', u'gs810emx'], u'tablets': [u'apple ipad pro', u'apple ipad mini', u'ipad'], u'gaming_consoles': [u'sony playstation 4', u'xbox one s', u'playstation'], u'range_of_days': 14}`.  with `{k:[i.lower() for i in v] if isinstance(v, list) else v  for k,v in my_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@User9367133**, don't use dictionary comprehension. It will not update `my_dict` instead it will pickup the elements of `my_dict` and creates new dictionary.

Once you pick any value pointed by any of the key in dictionary, please check if it's a list or not. If it's list then convert list of strings to lowercase.

If you want to originally update `my_dict`'s contents, do like this.

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/KMSLJ9545.

```
my_dict = {u'customer': [u'GS808E', u'GS810EMX'], u'tablets': [u'Apple IPAD PRO', u'Apple IPAD MINI', u'IPAD'], u'gaming_consoles': [u'SONY PLAYSTATION 4', u'XBOX ONE S', u'PLAYSTATION'], u'range_of_days': 14 };

for key in my_dict:
    if type(my_dict[key]) == type([]):
        for index, item in enumerate(my_dict[key]):
            my_dict[key][index] = item.lower();

print my_dict
```

» Output

```
{'gaming_consoles': ['sony playstation 4', 'xbox one s', 'playstation'], 'range_of_days': 14, 'tablets': ['apple ipad pro', 'apple ipad mini', 'ipad'], 'customer': ['gs808e', 'gs810emx']}
```

If you still prefer to use dictionary comprehension to create the new dictionary same as the above one then you can try the below code (but this is not that you want).

> Try it online at http://rextester.com/CEZ39339.

```
my_dict = {u'customer': [u'GS808E', u'GS810EMX'], u'tablets': [u'Apple IPAD PRO', u'Apple IPAD MINI', u'IPAD'], u'gaming_consoles': [u'SONY PLAYSTATION 4', u'XBOX ONE S', u'PLAYSTATION'], u'range_of_days': 14 };

my_dict = { key: ([item.lower() for item in my_dict[key]] if type(my_dict[key]) == type([]) else my_dict[key])  for key in my_dict}

print my_dict
```

» Output

```
{u'customer': [u'gs808e', u'gs810emx'], u'tablets': [u'apple ipad pro', u'apple ipad mini', u'ipad'], u'gaming_consoles': [u'sony playstation 4', u'xbox one s', u'playstation'], u'range_of_days': 14}
```